# Regarding python being a dynamically typed language

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, variable-assignment

it is a well known fact that Python is a dynamically typed language. I came to learn Python from Java and something I have been wondering is, in Java, we do variable assignments as,

```
int testVariable = 5;
```

Once the above code is executed, Java allocates a location of memory that is able to hold a value of **type integer** and calls it testVariable. So when we change the value of the variable, java just updates the **value** of the testVariable and it **does not have to change the type of the variable** since we can not assign a string to an int. So in the **same memory location,** only the value will be updated.

Then, let us suppose that we do the following in Python,

```
myVariable = 5
```

Now, since the value here is 5 and the type of the value is int, Python creates a memory location which can hold a value of type int and stores the value (5 in this case) in that memory location.

Then, I can bound the variable name 'myVariable' to a value with the type string like below,

```
myVariable = 'Test String'
```

So once this is done, **does Python move the memory location where the value 5 was saved before, to somewhere else suitable to save a value of string (since the first location has been suitable to save integers in the first place and not strings) and give this new memory location the name myVariable? Or, does python just modify the memory location where the integer values was stored, so that it can hold a string value now?**

Please shed some light on this. Thank you.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the variable names are just references to where the objects are stored, where the object has type.

So, when you change `myVariable` from `5` to `'Test String'` the variable reference `myVariable` changes to refer to the new string location.